# mySQL inner join over multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

If i post this Lines of Code:

```
SELECT Cheese.Chesse_Name
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.Orders_ID = OrderSandwich.Orders_ID
INNER JOIN OrderSandwich ON OrderSandwich.Sandwich_ID = Sandwich.Sandwich_ID
INNER JOIN Sandwich ON Sandwich.Cheese_ID = Cheese.Cheese_ID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = 1;
```

All i get from the DB is an Error

```
Fehler

SQL-Befehl: Dokumentation

SELECT Cheese.Chesse_Name
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.Orders_ID = OrderSandwich.Orders_ID
INNER JOIN OrderSandwich ON OrderSandwich.Sandwich_ID = Sandwich.Sandwich_ID
INNER JOIN Sandwich ON Sandwich.Cheese_ID = Cheese.Cheese_ID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = 1
 LIMIT 0, 25 

MySQL meldet: Dokumentation
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'Customer'
```

I'm now trying this for several hours not to say the hole day.

Here is the DB Diagram:

[image]

I would be very greatful if somebody right away see the mistake i'm makeing

Comment: Well you're selecting from customer twice once on the from and once on the first join.  If you do need a self join, you have to alias the tables so the database engine knows what table you mean.  I also see you stating cheese.cheese_Id but I don't see a table Cheese or alias of cheese in the select.

Comment: Also, the order of the joins is important.  You can't join orders to orderswandwich wihtout first declaring the ordersSandwich table..

Comment: I think you've bitten off more than you can chew. This is really easy but still, you need to start with something simpler and gradually build up complexity.

Comment: That was not the thought of the teacher as he gave us this task without instructing us on simple join elements -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to join `Customer` table with itself. Reorganize your `JOIN` queries like following.

```
SELECT Cheese.Cheese_Name
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customer.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN OrderSandwich ON Orders.Orders_ID = OrderSandwich.Orders_ID
INNER JOIN Sandwich ON OrderSandwich.Sandwich_ID = Sandwich.Sandwich_ID
INNER JOIN Cheese ON Sandwich.Cheese_ID = Cheese.Cheese_ID
WHERE Customer.Customer_ID = 1;
```

Remember, you are calling the `JOIN` statement, to join the mentioned table with the table above. For an example, if you call

```
Customer
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customer.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID
```

You are joining the `Customer` Table with the `Orders` table. No need to mention `Customer` table twice.

Comment: Don't they just need to remove that line entirely since the next one is for orders?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Cheese.Chesse_Name
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customer.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN OrderSandwich ON Orders.Orders_ID = OrderSandwich.Order_ID
INNER JOIN Sandwich ON OrderSandwich.Sandwich_ID = Sandwich.Sandwich_ID
INNER JOIN Cheese ON Sandwich.Cheese_ID = Cheese.Cheese_ID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just seems to me you need to shift all the inner join tables up one and change the last to cheese. (removing the unneeded/desired 2nd join to customers)

```
SELECT Cheese.Chesse_Name
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customer.Customer_ID = Orders.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN Ordersandwich ON Orders.Orders_ID = OrderSandwich.Orders_ID
INNER JOIN sandwich ON OrderSandwich.Sandwich_ID = Sandwich.Sandwich_ID
INNER JOIN cheese ON Sandwich.Cheese_ID = Cheese.Cheese_ID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = 1;
```